# docx4j NullPointerException in ObfuscatedFontPart.deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles

Tags: java, ubuntu, docx4j

I am using docx4j to convert a docx file to html in my software. I am developing in a windows based system and my production is a Ubuntu Linux 14.04 in AWS. Everything works well in Windows, But when it comes to Ubuntu, it is throwing me an exception as follows.

> 2015-11-19 07:33:36 ERROR AbstractExporter:108 - Exception exporting
>   package   java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ObfuscatedFontPart.deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles(ObfuscatedFontPart.java:263)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.FontTablePart.deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles(FontTablePart.java:161)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:91)
>     at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toHTML(Docx4J.java:511)    at
>   com.testbudha.document.impl.WordDocumentExtractor.toHtml(WordDocumentExtractor.java:31)
>     at
>   com.testbudha.document.impl.DocXExtractor.getText(DocXExtractor.java:31)
>     at
>   com.testbudha.document.impl.DocumentServiceImpl.getFileText(DocumentServiceImpl.java:18)
>     at
>   com.testbudha.server.controller.StudentHomeController.getResumeText(StudentHomeController.java:120)

I know it's a font related issue and I tried installing

> ttf-mscorefonts-installer

But it doesn't change anything I also tried installing the vista fonts by using this script. Then also I am getting the same exception

[Vista fonts installer](http://plasmasturm.org/code/vistafonts-installer/vistafonts-installer)

```
protected String toHtml(WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage, String path, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws Docx4JException {
        try {

            HTMLSettings htmlSettings = Docx4J.createHTMLSettings();
            htmlSettings.setImageDirPath(path + "/_files");
            htmlSettings.setImageTargetUri(request.getContextPath() + "/getfile/");
            htmlSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);

            OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Docx4jProperties.setProperty("docx4j.Convert.Out.HTML.OutputMethodXML", true);
            Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
            String outputHtml = ((ByteArrayOutputStream) os).toString().replaceAll("Â", "\n").replaceAll(" â€“ ", "-")
                    .replaceAll("(?s)â€.\\s*", "").replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]","").replaceAll("#\\?", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s*(?i)HYPERLINK\\s\\S\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))+\"", "($1)")
                    .replaceAll("(\\([^)]*\\))\\s?(\\w+)", "$2$1");
            return outputHtml;
        } finally {
            if (wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFontTablePart() != null) {
                wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getFontTablePart().deleteEmbeddedFontTempFiles();
            }
        }
```

it is throwing exception at

```
Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
```

Comment: What version of docx4j are you using?

Comment: what about developing in a production Ubuntu box with a vagrant box which is Windows? even if you solve this specific problem you will have a long string of new ones coming.

Comment: @sarah.ferguson we have been doing this for long. This is the first time we ran in to a problem like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/ObfuscatedFontPart.java#L263

tmpFontDir seems to be null, probably because System.getProperty("user.home") returns null

so set the property "docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ObfuscatedFontPart.tmpFontDir" in Docx4j.properties file added to your classpath.

Comment: its "docx4j.properties" not "Docx4j.properties"